# Why failing to install Packages in Synaptic of Debian 8.5?

Tags: debian, system-installation, synaptic

I mark some packages for installation but I get Fig. 1 Asking to insert the installer DVD again in `/media/cdrom` but I have only its USB installer media and it does not want to have it, Fig. 2 List of failures without successful step 1

[image]
[image]

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB installer media contains a CD image, that's what Synaptic's looking for.

To fix this, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, remove the `cdrom` entries and make sure you have entries like

```
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

instead (choose an appropriate [mirror](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list) close to you!). Once you've done that, refreshing in Synaptic should allow you to install packages.

If you really want to use the CD image on your USB key, leave the `cdrom` entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, insert your USB key, mount it and look for a file with an `iso` extension and a name starting with `debian` (*e.g.* `debian-8.5.0-amd64-netinst.iso`), then run

```
mount -t iso9660 -o loop /path/to/debian.iso /media/cdrom
```

as `root`. Synaptic will then be able to use the files there too. Before you remove your USB key, run

```
umount /media/cdrom
```

as `root`. If you used the small USB images to install Debian, you won't save much by doing this — the images contain a very small number of packages.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file  and comment the following line:

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie...
```

like this:

```
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie...
```

save and update

**Edit**

You can use the debian ISO as repo:

```
mkdir /media/mountpoint  
mount -t iso9660 -o loop /path/to/debian.iso /media/mountpoint 
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line:

```
deb file:///media/mountpoint jessie main contrib
```

Update

Comment: Yes, i will edit my answer